# Error de conexión a la base de datos cuando en realidad estoy obteniendo un objeto conexión

Tags: php, mysqli

Al momento en que trato de realizar la conexión, ésta falla. Realicé un `var_dump($enlace)`, para poder ver si se realiza y me manda este mensaje:

> object(mysqli)#1 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(13) "mysqlnd 8.1.6" ["client_version"]=> int(80106) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(15) "10.4.24-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(100424) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(278) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

Y este es el código para la conexión:

```
<?php
  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario = "root";
  $clave = "";
  $baseDeDatos = "pagina";

  $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
  var_dump($enlace);
  if (!$enlace){
    echo "error en el servidor";
  }
?>
```

Comment: intenta cambiando el if por `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("La Conneccion a fallado por: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
`dado que en ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) osea que no hay errores, en todo caso te recomiendo ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Comment: @Bryro muchas gracias por comentar, solo me cambio a al mismo mensaje, solo cambiando la ultima parte del mensaje 
 ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(282) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Pero si `var_dump($enlace)` te pinta todo eso, diría que sí que te está conectando, porque la función `mysqli_connect()` devuelve un objeto que representa la conexión (en caso de éxito), o `false` (en caso contrario). ¿Dónde está el error? No creo que te pinte "error en el servidor", si es así prueba a cambiar `if (!$enlace){` por `if ($enlace === false){`.

Comment: @Daniela como te muestra ese mensaje si obvimante te lo formatie y deberia decir la coneccion falla y el motivo en el caso de que no, es que se esta realizando existosa adjunte tambien el link para que vieras los ejemplos...

Comment: Realmente no entiendo tu problema. ¿No será que intentas usar la conexión en otro sitio haciendo `include` o `require` y pones mal el nombre de la variable o usas otro archivo donde sí falla la conexión? Sugiero que pongas esto así y nos cuentas qué ves ahora en pantalla: `if (!$enlace){ echo "error en la conexión"; }else{ printf ("Conexión exitosa. La variable se llama $%s, por favor, usa ese nombre para trabajar con ella","enlace"); }` Si te dice que es exitosa entonces usa la conexión y si falla, muéstranos en el código que implementas para usar la conexión.